# group the record by columns and wanted to pick only the max of created date record using mapping data flows azure data factory

Tags: azure-data-factory

HI there in Mapping data flows and azure data factory. I tried to create data flow in that we used aggregate transformation to group the records, now there is a column called [createddate] now we want to pick the max of created record and out put should show all the columns.

any advice please help me

Answer (score 0):

The Aggregate transformation will only output the columns participating in the aggregation (group by and aggregate function columns). To include all of the columns in the Aggregate output, add a new column pattern to your aggregate (see pic below ... change column1, column2, ... to the names of the columns you are already using in your agg)

[image]

Comment: initialy i used this but using first pipeline is not considering latest created record from the duplicates

Comment: Use last() instead then